# Code deletes the content of the file rather than replacing a text

Tags: java, text, java-io

In my below code I wanted to replace the text "DEMO" with "Demographics" but instead of  replacing the text it deletes the entire content of the text file.

Contents inside the file:
DEMO
data
morning

PS: I'm a beginner in java

```
package com.replace.main;

import java.io.*;

public class FileEdit {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    String readLine, replacedData;
    try {

        bw = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(
                        "Demg.ctl"));

        br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(
                        "Demg.ctl"));

        System.out.println(br.readLine()); //I Get Null Printed Here
        while ((readLine = br.readLine())!= null) {
            System.out.println("Inside While Loop");
            System.out.println(readLine);
            if (readLine.equals("DEMO")) {
                System.out.println("Inside if loop");
                replacedData = readLine.replaceAll("DEMO","Demographics");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("After While");
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You open a Writer to your file, but you don't write anything. This means that your file is replaced with an empty file.

Besides this you also need to close your writer, not just the reader.

And last but not least, your if condition is wrong.

```
 if (readLine.equals("DEMO")) {
```

should read

```
 if (readLine.contains("DEMO")) {
```

Otherwise it would only return true if your line contained "DEMO" but nothing else.

Comment: thanks. But how do I open a Writer to replace the contents of a file ?. do I need to remove the FileWriter from my code?

Comment: `new FileWriter("Demg.ctl")` in your code creates this writer. You can just write to your variable `bw`.

Comment: There is no way to merely "replace" some text in a file if the replacement text is not the same length as the original text.  You must COPY the entire file to the output, performing the replacement while you copy, then delete the original and rename the output to the old name.

Comment: FileWriter implicitly replaces the existing file when writing, unless you tell it to `append`.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you just show me how to do that? I'm not able to get    it.

Comment: The problem is probably that you create the Writer before reading. Try to first read the contents of the file, then create the Writer and write the new contents. Don't forget to close the Writer.

Comment: I tried creating the FileWriter inside "if" condition still it creates a new file. How do I write to my variable "bw" without creating a new FileWriter.

Comment: As soon as you create the FileWriter it will replace the existing file. So you should only do this when you have read all the content of the file. Maybe you should start with writing to a different file.

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm updating the answer to my own question.

package com.replace.main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileEdit
    {
     public static void main(String args[])
         {
         try
             {
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Demg.ctl"));
             String readLine = ""; 
             String oldtext = "";
             while((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                 {
                 oldtext += readLine + "\r\n";
             }
             reader.close();
             // To replace the text
             String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("DEMO", "Demographics");

             FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Demg.ctl");
             writer.write(newtext);
             writer.close();
         }
         catch (IOException e)
             {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```